# Parse CURL XML response PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

Please tell me how can i get $String value for key *field name="Contact Tags (Raw)"*
Basically i need something like this:

**$XML->result->contact->Group_Tag("Sequences and Tags")->field("Contact Tags (Raw)")**

This is result I got

[image]

**MY PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
$data = <<<STRING
<search>
    <equation>
    <field>E-Mail</field>
    <op>e</op>
    <value>anast@gmail.com</value>
    </equation>
</search>
STRING;

$data = urlencode(urlencode($data));

$appid = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$reqType = "search";
$postargs = "appid=".$appid."&key=".$key."&reqType=".$reqType."&data=".$data;
$request = "https://api.moon-ray.com/cdata.php";

$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postargs);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);
header("Content-Type: text/xml");
$decoded = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $response);
echo $decoded;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
$string = '<result>
<contact id="90676">
<Group_Tag name="Sequences and Tags">
    <field name="Contact Tags (Raw)">
        test test
    </field>
</Group_Tag>
</contact>
</result>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

if($xml->contact->Group_Tag['name'] == 'Sequences and Tags'){
    if($xml->contact->Group_Tag->field['name'] == 'Contact Tags (Raw)'){
        echo $xml->contact->Group_Tag->field;
    }
}
```

Updated

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("http://i.shn-host.ru/json/srch.php") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

    foreach ($xml->contact->Group_Tag as $Group_Tag) {
        if($Group_Tag['name'] == 'Sequences and Tags'){
            foreach ($Group_Tag as $field) {
                if($field['name'] == 'Contact Tags (Raw)'){
                    echo $field;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Result I got

> 22*/*96*/*72*/*77*/*78*/*79*/*82*/*105*/*121*/*136*/*146*/*209*/*246*/*259*/*260*/*262*/*264*/*281*/*282

Comment: Thanks! I can get an empty page if i use **$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);** Maybe the problem is that my **$response = curl_exec($session);** isn't a string?

Comment: Try to remove this header("Content-Type: text/xml");
$decoded = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $response);

Comment: i removed it before answering 
*- header/- $decoded/- and echo $decoded*...

And if it will be helpful - i can't even **echo $xml->contact** - the page is blank.

Comment: print_r($xml->contact); not echo.

Comment: And set ini_set('display_errors', 1); when you testing something